Will wood filler adhere properly and still be effective if applied on top of an area where spackle was applied first, but sanded off?
I want to use DAP Premium Wood Filler on my primed wood door casings and window trim. It's my understanding that wood filler is the best choice for this application ... it's more reliable and delivers better strength.
Initially, spackle was used, but it has since been sanded off.
Will the wood filler adhere correctly and still be effective if applied?
Or will there be any issues with the wood filler adhering because the spackle was applied on the wood trim first? Again, it has since been sanded off.
Thanks in advance for any replies.

Should be fine. Spackle shouldn't be absorbed by the material, so if sanded off it should simply be gone.

Hello @keshlam, thank you!

Might want to use wire brush first in case there's any spackle left in the wood grain.
